# Why Array(1).join('str') output empty?

Tags: javascript

Why below block of code not output string ?

I was expecting it should display abc when we pass num=1.

What I am missing here ?

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  return Array(num).join(str);
}
console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 1));
```

Comment: How can you join one item with no other items with a delimiter?

Comment: @mplungjan I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need at least two elements for [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with a separator, because one element is just converted to a string and it does not need any *glue*.

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
    return Array(num + 1).join(str);
}
console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a string to be repeated n times, use ES6's `String.repeat`, like so:

`'myString'.repeat(repeatTimes);`

Or an array-based solution (not recommended for your problem, though):

`new Array(repeatTimes).fill('myString').join('');`

If you need ES5 solution, use `lodash` fn `repeat`:

`_.repeat('abc', 2);`

Comment: Fill is not supported by IE

Comment: You can always use a polyfill, which is found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: or just do `Array(num + 1).join(str);`

Comment: @mplungjan "Fill is not supported by IE" Yes and ?  Fortunately IE is globally not the standard any longer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#W3Counter_.28May_2007_to_June_2017.29 (6,2% usage share)

Comment: @davidxxx 6.2% for you  - 10% for me -> 600K requests per week (IE7-15) - feel free to ignore IE. I certainly cannot and will not.

Comment: @mplungjan  6 or 10% are not significant. I don't say that we have to ignore IE in any case but this remark : "doesn't work on IE" doesn't make sense today in a general Q/A now as IE is not a standard any longer even in the companies. It was relevant 5 or 10 years ago. "doesn't work on Chrome" could make more sense today but as Chrome supports most of things to support, it is rather uncommon to hear it :)

Comment: Happy for you that you write for a company that can ignore 10% of their visitors. Good luck ;) I did not write "Best viewed with IE" - just that defensive coding and paying attention to support is important

Answer (score -2):

The correct way should be

```
str.repeat(num)
```